# Vim: how to use ci (change inside) with multiple occurrences per line

Tags: vim

In a line like this:

```
something "one!", "and two", "and three", "and more"
```

How should I use the command ci" to replace "and three"?

I have tried some made up combos with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First navigate to the desired substring:

```
/three
```

or in the line:

```
f";;;;
```

(which moves to the next `"` 5 times)

or

```
f,;
```

Then, `ci"` zaps the string leaving the cursor for insert inside the empty quotes

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking for some combo with "ci" itself as ci3"  ... but your proposals are awesome.

Comment: Oh, in that vein, you could of course `4;` to repeat the last fF/tT search movement

Comment: Or even `5f"` instead of `;` at all

Answer (score 1):

Move into substring:

> 2fa

Then replace and three:

> ci"